# Wordpress Comments on Posts - function.php hack

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I found this article on how to get my comments box to show on my mobile site.

https://metinsaylan.com/4571/how-to-enable-comments-for-all-posts-in-wordpress/

This assumes that my table prefix is "wp_" however my prefix is "wp_svkc_"

First question is how do I modify the below code to account for the different prefix.

```
function enable_comments_for_all(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET comment_status = 'open'")); // Enable comments
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET ping_status = 'open'")); // Enable trackbacks
} enable_comments_for_all();
```

and 2. where in my function.php for my theme do I put it so it doesn't throw error when I update it?

```
    <?php
/**
 * Cenote functions and definitions
 *
 * @link    https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package cenote
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'cenote_setup' ) ) :
    /**
     * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
     *
     * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
     * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
     * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
     */
    function cenote_setup() {
        /*
         * Make theme available for translation.
         * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
         * If you're building a theme based on cenote, use a find and replace
         * to change 'cenote' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
         */
        load_theme_textdomain( 'cenote', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        /*
         * Let WordPress manage the document title.
         * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
         * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
         * provide it for us.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        /*
         * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
         *
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        /**
         * Enable support for post formats
         *
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/post-formats/
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'link', 'image', 'quote', 'video', 'audio' ) );

        // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'tg-menu-primary'    => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'cenote' ),
            'tg-menu-header-top' => esc_html__( 'Header Top', 'cenote' ),
        ) );

        /*
         * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
         * to output valid HTML5.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
            'search-form',
            'comment-form',
            'comment-list',
            'gallery',
            'caption',
        ) );

        // Set up the WordPress core custom background feature.
        add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'cenote_custom_background_args', array(
            'default-color' => 'ffffff',
            'default-image' => '',
        ) ) );

        // Add theme support for selective refresh for widgets.
        add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );

        /**
         * Add support for core custom logo.
         *
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo
         */
        add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
            'height'      => 250,
            'width'       => 250,
            'flex-width'  => true,
            'flex-height' => true,
        ) );

        add_editor_style();
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cenote_setup' );

/**
 * Custom image sizes for theme.
 */
function cenote_image_sizes() {

    // Set default post thumbnail. 16:9.
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 768, 432, true );
    // Large full width image.
    add_image_size( 'cenote-full-width', 1160, 653, true );
    // 3:4.
    add_image_size( 'cenote-post', 600, 400, true );
    // Auto size.
    add_image_size( 'cenote-post-auto', 600, 9999, false );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cenote_image_sizes' );
/**
 * Set the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 *
 * Priority 0 to make it available to lower priority callbacks.
 *
 * @global int $content_width
 */
function cenote_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'cenote_content_width', 640 );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cenote_content_width', 0 );

/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/#registering-a-sidebar
 */
function cenote_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'cenote' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'cenote' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer 1', 'cenote' ),
        'id'            => 'footer-sidebar-1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here to show on footer 1.', 'cenote' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer 2', 'cenote' ),
        'id'            => 'footer-sidebar-2',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here to show on footer 2.', 'cenote' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer 3', 'cenote' ),
        'id'            => 'footer-sidebar-3',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here to show on footer 3.', 'cenote' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer 4', 'cenote' ),
        'id'            => 'footer-sidebar-4',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here to show on footer 4.', 'cenote' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'cenote_widgets_init' );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function cenote_scripts() {
    $suffix = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min';

    wp_enqueue_style( 'cenote-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themegrill-icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/themegrill-icons' . $suffix . '.css', '1.0' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'cenote-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix' . $suffix . '.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hammer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/hammer' . $suffix . '.js', array(), '2.0.8', true );

    // Load Swiper on Gallery post format.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'swiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/swiper' . $suffix . '.js', array(), '4.2.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'swiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/swiper' . $suffix . '.css', '4.2.0' );

    // Load headroom if sticky header is enabled.
    if ( true === get_theme_mod( 'cenote_header_sticky_option', true ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'headroom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/headroom' . $suffix . '.js', array(), '0.9.4', true );
    }

    // Only load masonry script if enabled.
    if ( ( is_archive() || is_home() ) && 'tg-archive-style--masonry' === get_theme_mod( 'cenote_archive_style', 'tg-archive-style--masonry' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/masonry.pkgd' . $suffix . '.js', array(), '4.2.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd' . $suffix . '.js', array(), '4.1.4', true );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'cenote-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/cenote-custom' . $suffix . '.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cenote_scripts' );

/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Functions which enhance the theme by hooking into WordPress.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-functions.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Meta boxes.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/meta-boxes.php';

/**
 * Widget for showing recent post
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets/class-cenote-widget-recent-posts.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
if ( defined( 'JETPACK__VERSION' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
}

/**
 * Load WooCommerce compatibility file.
 */
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/woocommerce.php';
}

/**
 * Add Kirki customizer library file
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/kirki/kirki.php';

/**
 * Add Kirki options file
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer/kirki-customizer.php';

/**
 * Add theme css class control file
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-css-class.php';

/**
 * Load breadcrumb trail file if enabled.
 */
if ( true === get_theme_mod( 'cenote_breadcrumb', true ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/compatibility/class-breadcrumb-trail.php';
}

/**
 * Load Demo Importer Configs.
 */
if ( class_exists( 'TG_Demo_Importer' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/demo-config.php';
}

/**
 * Load TGMPA Configs.
 */
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/tgm-plugin-activation/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/tgm-plugin-activation/tgmpa-cenote.php';
```

Comment: Why are you going through all this trouble to enable commenting? Why not just check the box in the admin section to enable them? Is there some customization that I'm missing that won't allow this?

Comment: I have already dont this but the comments box only shows up on the PC version not mobile or tablet and it also only shows on new post not existing ones

Comment: Ah, so you want to run this code so that comments are enabled on all previous posts and the code has nothing to do with the issue of the comments visibility on mobile?

Comment: i want it on all previous posts as it is not showing despite being enabled. It is also not showing mobile so i want to kill two birds with one stone. function.php runs on load.

Comment: I don't see how the code you have will resolve comments not being visible on mobile. Is it at all possible that css (bootstrap?) is causing comments to not display on mobile? Additionally, from the admin panel you can bulk edit your old posts to enable comments.